# How do you make a link perform an action without reloading a page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hyperlink

The clearest example of this I could think of is the Reddit Upvote/downvote buttons how when you click the button, the value for upvotes is updated, the upvote button lights up, and the page DOES NOT reload, you just stay exactly where you are on the page.

I am trying to make a feature similar to this and I can totally figure out how to do it with reloading, but I want it to not reload so the user experience isn't disrupted.

Is it possible to do this with php? or would I need to use javascript or something?

The action I would need it to perform would be a basic update query in the database.

Comment: you need to use AJAX for such purposes!

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

With AJAX you can send a request in the background.
The easiest way is to use the jquery libary for this.

You can also output some data as JSON back to the script if you want to take some other actions depending on the result from that query.

A good tutorial is [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp).
It also explains how this requests (called: XMLHttpRequest) work.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to contact a server to either send it some state or to retrieve some state from the server (or both), then you would use AJAX with javascript in order to contact the server without reloading the page.  You can then also use javascript to update the state of your page after the operation.  That is generally what the Reddit page you refer to is doing.

Conceptually, you'd set up your page like this:

1. Put the link on the page.
2. With javascript install an event handler so you are notified of a click on the link.
3. When the link is clicked, your event handler will be called.
4. Prevent the default behavior of the link so the browser doesn't navigate to a new page.
5. Then, in the event handler, send your data to the server using AJAX.  You will obviously need a URL on your server and server process that can accept and process the data for you and return a value if you need to.
6. If you need the response from the server, then set up a callback function for when the AJAX call completes (this will be some indeterminate time in the future).
7. Then, if you need to change the current page in any way (like show one more upvote), then you can modify the current page with javascript to show that new state.

Ajax is easier to use with a library (like jQuery) that contains some ajax support code, but you can certainly implement it in plain javascript too.

Here's [one example](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) of ajax with plain javscript. You can find many other examples with Google.

This [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) on AJAX seems pretty helpful too to show you how it works.

Comment: Exactly what i said in my answer.

Comment: @Michael - I hardly think our answers are the same.

Comment: Congrats on your edit. Now i know how you got to your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with an Ajax call to your php script. Ajax is designed for these asynchronous updates and/or reloads.

Another way you can do this is with HTML5 WebSockets. You could have the client send a trigger to the server when the user clicks the upvote, and then the server could update and push back the data. It would, however, be a bit overfill for this.

Comment: @Michael take a look now.

Comment: @jeroen would you mind upvoting to clear things out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to do this.  Here's a quick sample:

```
<a href="#" id="upvoteBtn">Vote Up</a>
```

Simple solution in JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("upvoteBtn");
el.addEventListener("click", onVoteClick);

function onVoteClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nDmB6/)'s a fiddle.

**NOTE:** I see you'd be updating the database.  In that case, you would have to use AJAX in the `onVoteClick` function (or use XMLHttpRequest) for this.  JavaScript is a client-side programming language and will not be able to communicate to the server without the use of AJAX or XMLHttpRequest.  Using the jQuery library, you should be able to [write AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) pretty easy.

Comment: FYI, `return false` doesn't do anything from an event handler installed with `addEventListener()`.  It works from an `onclick` handler specified in the HTML or works from a jQuery event handler, but not from this kind of event handler.  `e.preventDefault()` should already take care of it for you in modern browsers that support `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're absolutely right, I didn't realize that was the case.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Javascript's  XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score -2):

You can use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)...
It allows you to use JavaScript (client side) to call server side functions. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)'s a good example.